# Designating character column when reading unformatted fortran binary file with Python

Tags: python, fortran, binaryfiles

Designating character column when reading unformatted fortran binary file with Python

I need to read an originating from Fortran binary file which contains the following columns:
C1 integer*4
C2 integer*4
C3 character (len=9)
…
Cn double

I'm reading the file in Python in the following way:

```
f = FortranFile(inFile, 'r' )
dt = np.dtype([('c1','int32'),
               ('c2','int32'),
               …
               ('cn','int32'),
arr = np.fromfile(inFile,dt)
```

However, I don't know how to designate the C3 variable. With trial and error (judging by the output from other columns which I'm able to verify) it seems that C3 is five bytes long but I still don't know how to write that properly in the dt.

(for now, just to get the code working, I have two dummy columns, C3a and C3b, designated as int8 and float64, this at least gives me correct values in the following columns)

Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Comment: `character (len=9)` should not be five bytes long.

Comment: I have just found a fix, replacing the two dummy columns with:

                   ('C3','S9')

The extracted values are as expected, with the remaining columns unchanged (i.e. correct as well)